# Passing WebApi data to FullCalendar - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, fullcalendar

I have been trying to pass value returned from webapi to a fullcalendar but it is not working. It seems fullcalendar is loading before the webapi call even when the call is placed before

```
dataService.getItems(baseAddressSchoolCalendar + '/GetSchoolCalendarItems')
       .success(function (data) {

           $scope.events = data;

       })
       .error(function () {

       });

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
$scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
```

HTML:

```
<div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" calendar="myCalendar1" class="calendar" data-ng-model="eventSources"></div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `fullcalender == $scope.eventSources`?

Comment: @RoyMiloh I don't understand what you mean. Can you be more specific.

Comment: ".. returned from webapi to a fullcalendar", what is `fullcalendar` in your code?

Comment: @RoyMiloh I have added the `html` part to the question.

Comment: Place `$scope.eventSources = [data]` inside the promise chain (= `success` method, which is deprecated btw).

Comment: I have already done that, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a ng-if in the div element in order to render the directive when your pomise is done, i.e., when the length of the array is greater than 0.

```
<div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" calendar="myCalendar1" class="calendar" data-ng-model="eventSources" ng-if="eventSources.length > 0"></div>
```

The way you are doing the directive is rendering before the pomise gets finished.

Comment: How do I fix this? I have been on this for hours.